# [iOS CoreImage]Does Photo Segmentation Mattes support for macOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, core-image

I watched WWDC 2019 session about "Introducing Photo Segmentation Mattes"
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/260/

I checked Apple documentation of "AVSemanticSegmentationMatte".
The api shows that it is available for macOS from macOS 10.15+ and Mac Catalyst 13.0+.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avsemanticsegmentationmatte?language=objc

I have tried to implement segmentation mattes in macOS.
"AVCapturePhotoOutput" class has a 'enabledSemanticSegmentationMatteTypes' in iOS.
But 'enabledSemanticSegmentationMatteTypes' is unavailable in macOS.

Do you know how to use AVSemanticSegmentationMatte in macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of features are not available when capturing on macOS because the camera in a MacBook simply doesn't provide the same capabilities. You can, however, load a segmentation matte that was baked into an image taken with an iPhone or iPad on macOS (that's why the type is also available there).